# can't compile beta version of igraph from github

Tags: r

I use DevTools tools to install
install_github("igraph/rigraph")

I can install "gaborcsardi/pkgconfig"  just fine, which is also required. But "igraph/rigraph" doesn't work. I need it because I'm using an experimental package that requires this version of igraph. I get the following error:

```
compilation terminated.
make: *** [foreign-graphml.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="igraph.dll" SHLIB_LIBADD='$(FLIBS)' WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 ' havde status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'igraph'
* removing 'C:/Users/emil/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/igraph'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

NOTE! the line "Warning: running command" in the code is translated by myself, since this was in my OS language which is danish.  I think it is an accurate translation, but the wording *might* be slightly different.

I'm on a 64-bit Windows. I also have Lubuntu 16.04 installed on the same machine, and there I don't have any problems with the install. I need to use the package on a windows machine, unfortunately. RTools 3.3 is installed.

I also filed this at the github page:
https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/165

Comment: Is RTools installed on your windows machine?

Comment: yes, a full install, version 3.3